# How to set an icon to a JFrame when using createAndShowGUI() method?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, icons, jframe

I am using a `createAndShowGUI()` method to create a `JFrame`. I am trying to set an icon, but when I run it in NetBeans, it doesn't show. However, when I run a `.jar` file (with the image in the same folder), then it works without a flaw.

```
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame game = new JFrame();
    game.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    game.setSize(198, 409);  
    game.setResizable(false);
    game.setTitle("Frame Title"); 
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("Icon.png");
    game.setIconImage(img.getImage());
    game.setVisible(true);

}
```

Any ideas where the problem could be?

Comment: Adding to below answers, make sure your case of the filename is correct, windows is not case sensitive for files names, but inside the JAR java is case sensitive. PS the reason the File is not showing unless run side by side is because you never added it as a resource to your package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run the above code with a test image, the icon is changed correctly. Add:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

to the method to display the folder where the image *should* be located & copy it there if necessary.

Comment: Thank you, it appears that the image was in the wrong place. Now it works. But I have a few buttons with icons that work normally, so it doesnt matter where the image is located when using getClass().getResource("image.png")?

Comment: @KubaSpatny Of course it matters. The code you mentions looks in the class path

Comment: @Robin I was asking because I had all the images in the same folder (where the class.java files are) and Button icons worked normally but the frame icon didn't..

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you make package like:

```
org.icon
```

and add icons to that package.

To set icon use this:

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(Game.class.getResource("/org/Icon/NameOfIcon.png"));
game.setIconImage(img.getImage());
```

You program will have no problems to find an icon.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get a npe when i try to access the resource. I was told this might be because i'm using a runnable jar file?