# How to make executable JAR app in Eclipse?

Tags: java

I've made some Java application, and I want to make executable JAR file. I've tried to use "Export"->"Runnable JAR file", and it works, but my application contains folders with images, and application executes without any images! But if I try to use "Export"->"JAR file", I make JAR file, but I can't execute it - click by file and get nothing! I choose main class, any resources, but my JAR file doesn't execute. Please, tell me, how can I fix it?

Comment: Where are those images? Tell me correct path.

Comment: MyProject/images/menu_icons/

Comment: Look at this example how to add icons properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258375/how-to-set-an-icon-to-a-jframe-when-using-createandshowgui-method/13259593#13259593 The way you are doing is not the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on *how* the images are loaded/used in your Java code. What works best for me, is to have a folder (package) in your project called something appropriate (e.g. "res" or "resources") and put everything that is not java code in there. Then you can load your resources using URLs that point to these resources. See example below:

```
URL css_url = getClass().getResource("/resource/style.css");
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the application to know where are the extra contents are (media, classes etc) it needs a manifest. The manifest should have been generated along with your eclipse setup, if it is you will need to edit it and input some paths.

If you dont have one you can simply create one.

Everything you need to know about manifests and how to do you can find here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Add img folder inside src folder of your project. Refresh the project. Export again to Executable Jar File

Answer (score 0):

Your JAR works fine, problem is in location of your images. You could create a new folder like: `images` inside of your project and put your icons in there. You will use this way to set icon on your menu:

```
nameOfComponent.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images/NameOfIcon.PNG"));
```

But the problem in this aproach is that you would have to "carry" your images folder with your JAR file:

[image]

Thats why you should consider this [aproach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258375/how-to-set-an-icon-to-a-jframe-when-using-createandshowgui-method/13259593#13259593)

You will get something like this in your Project Explorer:

[image]