# Eclipse - Exporting Runnable JAR File (alert popup)

Tags: java, eclipse, export, executable-jar

I'm totally misunderstanding something about exporting a project to a JAR.

2 things are happening.

First, I get an alert while exporting the Runnable JAR File:

**Exported with compile warnings: prj.Resources/classes/Person.java**

My Project is called **prj.HelloWorld**. The main function resides here.
It is also referencing another projects resources, which happens to be **prj.Resources**.
(I added that project to the Java Build Path for **prj.HelloWorld**)

So, the Person.java class is performing just fine, but I still get the compile warning.
What does that warning mean?

Second, when I double-click my helloworld.jar file, which I saved to my desktop, I don't see any images in the MenuBar Items.
I'm calling icons from within both projects.  When I run the compiler from inside Eclipse, everything shows fine.

-As I'm exporting the Runnable JAR File, I'm selecting the "**Extract required libraries into generated JAR**", under the Library handling option.

What am I doing wrong, with images?

Comment: Seems they are in wrong place.

Comment: You're right.  When I exported to the same directory as the prj.HelloWorld, it shows the images.

Comment: Have a look at my answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258375/how-to-set-an-icon-to-a-jframe-when-using-createandshowgui-method/13259593#13259593 Thats the best way to add icons in your Java project. P.S. If you don't work with multiple packages, just add icons in default package.

Comment: So, now I'm confused. If I want to send my friend the JAR file, how would he see the icons?  I assumed the JAR would contain all dependencies to reference.

Comment: By extracting jar file with WinRAR. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Window -> Show View -> Problems
```

This will open up a view which will show any problems in the program. Warnings are not critical, but notices of possibly deprecated functions and other things that should be changed.

Comment: This actually is helpful.  I only had the Console open. Nice to see any existing warnings, even if they're not a big deal

Answer (score 0):

The images are in wrong place/folder so that eclipse ignore them during the build process. 
If you don't have this folder(`src/resources`) try to create it and put your images in it

Comment: why not? what is your approach to this issue?

Comment: Because he will have to "carry" that `resource` folder with his jar file. Otherwise, icons will not be displayed.

Comment: The thing I notice is that I see the images fine, running it in Eclipse. It's when I export the JAR that images don't show.  The images do reside in the JAR, but not displayable in the program. It's obviously a path based issue.  Just not getting it

Comment: I got more specific just now, in this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943913/eclipse-loading-icon-resource-error

Comment: nice. that is also what i try to explane. the answer will be more pretty if you put all icons/images in a folder whether than directly  in src folder and get the icons with  getClass().asResource(src/resources/save.icon)

Comment: getClass().getResources(src/resources/save.icon)